# Magento2 - Catalog session does not work in product list toolbar

Tags: php, session, magento2

I have a problem with the toolbar options states. A toolbar has access only to GET param like `product_list_limit=15`. The web lost sort's data when you remove GET param or change category (unlike in version 1.x).

http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/women/tops-women/jackets-women.html?product_list_limit=15

I extend `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar` class and try to save data in session (`$this->_catalogSession->setData('abcd', '1234');`), but session is still empty.

I do this in other module and session works perfectly. I think the problem is in di.xml file with entries like:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Session\Storage" type="Magento\Framework\Session\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">catalog</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

or

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Session">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="storage" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Session\Storage</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Have you any idea?

Comment: include session object with di and use it to store values

Comment: problem is globally (all websites on magento2 do not work correctly on products list page). I test this on home page and session is work normal

Comment: that's way my advice is not using $this->_catalogSession in plp